# Postgres function - alias when returning SETOF

Tags: postgresql

I have a function which returns a SETOF text, currently it is returned with the same name as the function.

Is it possible to alias the result returned?

Using an alias will allow me to map the results to a property using Dapper without the need for a custom mapper class.

I've tried to return a single column table but the performance when doing that is 10X slower.

Comment: How did you measure that? Can you show both functions?

Comment: For me I wanted a way to rename `jsonb_each.key` and `jsonb_each.value` in `SELECT jsonb_each.* FROM foo, jsonb_each(bar)`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign any name to the result column by using an alias:

```
SELECT myfun AS othername FROM myfun();
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myfun() AS myfun(othername);
```